# 3 Pin IR receiver Schematic

Tags: schematics, infrared

I have been looking for this on google and couldn't find it, what does the schematic look like for a 3 pin IR receiver (ground, +5v, out)?

Comment: When I need to draw a schematic *symbol* for a component I usually refer to the manufacturer's datasheet and try to do something that resembles their representation.

Answer (score 2):

It can be represented like in this schematic taken from [sherkhan.net](http://www.sherkhan.net/blogs/frikadas/?m=200903):

[image]

[CadSoft EAGLE](http://cadsoftusa.com) draws it like this:

[image]